# Unable to open port 81

Tags: apache-2.2

Im very new to apache2 stuff... and I'm learning about virtualhost, I tried putting my configuration as like this, the port doesn't open. Any idea what went wrong? Kindly guide me.

**000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    #ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5001/
        #ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5001/


    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/poke1
    #DocumentRoot /var/www/html/poke


    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =abc.com
#RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:81>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    #ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
        #ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5001/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5001/


    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    #DocumentRoot /var/www/html/poke1
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/poke


    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =abc.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

**000-default-le-ssl.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    #ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
        #ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5001/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5001/


    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    #DocumentRoot /var/www/html/poke1
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/poke

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/abc.com/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/abc.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
ServerName abc.com
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/abc.com/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
</IfModule>
```

Just incase if you didn't aware, when using port 80 it should go to 127.0.0.1:5000 else if port 81 it should go to 127.0.0.1:5001

Comment: What error message do you get in your browser ?

Comment: @Iain This site can’t be reached

Comment: What do your logs say ? Is the firewall open ?

Comment: @Iain It is opened

Answer (score 1):

Add this to /etc/apache/ports.conf right below Listen 80 if you have'nt already:

```
Listen 81
```

This enables apache to listen on port 81 also.

Also don't forget to run

```
service apache2 restart
```